# Flutter create grid with custom borders from array

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

How to draw custom border in a grid that can also act as a barrier. Example in image below:

[image: Grid example]

I have been able to fill whole cells so far (using Offset to mark individual cells), but no luck with adding borders.

Code that I have so far:

```
List<List<String>> gridState = [
['', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''],
['', '', '', 'x', '', '', '', ''],
['', '', '', '', '', '', 'x', ''],
['', '', 'x', 'x', '', '', '', ''],
['', 'x', '', '', '', '', '', ''],
['', '', '', '', '', 'x', '', ''],
['', 'x', '', '', '', '', '', ''],
['', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''],
];

Widget _buildGrid() {
int gridStateLength = gridState.length;
return Column(children: <Widget>[
  AspectRatio(
    aspectRatio: 1.0,
    child: Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(color: Colors.black, width: 2.0)),
      child: GridView.builder(
        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
          crossAxisCount: gridStateLength,
        ),
        itemBuilder: _buildGridItems,
        itemCount: gridStateLength * gridStateLength,
      ),
    ),
  ),
]);
}


 Widget _buildGridItems(BuildContext context, int index) {
int gridStateLength = gridState.length;
int x, y = 0;
x = (index / gridStateLength).floor();
y = (index % gridStateLength);
return GestureDetector(
  onTap: () {
    setState(() {
      x++;

      print('$x,$y');
    });
  },
  child: GridTile(
    child: Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(color: Colors.black, width: 0.5)),
      child: Center(
        child: _buildGridItem(x, y),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
}
 Widget _buildGridItem(int x, int y) {
if (gridState[x][y].contains('x')) {
  return Container(
    color: Colors.black,
  );
} else {
  return Text('');
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Can you include your current snippet that you;ve tried so far

Comment: Updated with code I have so far!

Comment: One more question, Would you like to just have container Text on border,

Comment: To be precise, a border that can act as a barrier, for example in a labyrinth